# How to stop multiple API fetches in React

Tags: reactjs, api, fetch-api, use-effect

I'm really new to React so please understand if my explanation is not enough(I'll do my best to explain)

So what I'm trying to do is fetch an api, store it in a state variable, and make a button(that will toggle the toggle function) and so on...

```
const [randomPokemon, setRandomPokemon] = React.useState([])
    const [specifics, setSpecifics] = React.useState({})
    const [pokemonIndex, setPokemonIndex] = React.useState(1)
    const [disableButton, setDisableButton] = React.useState(false)

    React.useEffect(function() {
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonIndex}/`).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setRandomPokemon(prevState => data))
    }, [pokemonIndex])

    
    function disableBtn() {
        setDisableButton(prevState => !prevState);
        setTimeout((setDisableButton), 500)
    }
    
    
    function getRandomIndex(lowerBound, upperBound) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (upperBound - lowerBound + 1)) + lowerBound;
    };
    
    
    function toggle(e) {
        const randomIndex = getRandomIndex(1, 898);
        e.preventDefault();
        setPokemonIndex(randomIndex);
        const newPokemon = {
            pokemonName: randomPokemon.name,
            pokemonId: randomPokemon.id,
            pokemonType: randomPokemon.types.map(type => type.type.name),
            pokemonAbility: randomPokemon.abilities.map(ability => ability.ability.name),
            pokemonImage: randomPokemon.sprites.other[`official-artwork`].front_default
        };
        disableBtn();
        setSpecifics(newPokemon)
    }
```

However, when I console log "specifics" I get this in my console. [console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy6qy.png)

Question: Is there any way to stop making my program to fetch multiple times (because I think fetching the same data three times will lead to performance issues.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

each update state or change property run useEffect method again

```js
 React.useEffect(function() {
    const fetchData=async ()=>{ fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonIndex}/`)
    .then(res => res.json()).then(data => setRandomPokemon(prevState => data))
  }
  if(randomPokemon?.length===0)
    fetchData();
}, [pokemonIndex])
```

Comment: You're right but he not clearing the state before making another request so at the first time it will run fine but the second time it will not make any API request.

Comment: sure I agree, I don't know the hole of the scenario I just suggested a solution to solve the problem.

Comment: Every time I click, I want to state variable that holds the pokemon data to be overwritten with the new one

Comment: on the onClick you must call `setRandomPokemon([])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use one extra `pokemonIndex` variable which stores the previous index and write one condition in `useEffect` whether you get a new `index` value then the previous one then only you have to make an API call.

```
const [pokemonIndex, setPokemonIndex] = React.useState(1)
const [pereviousPokemonIndex, setPrevPokemonIndex] = React.useState(0)

React.useEffect(function() {
        if(pokemonIndex !== pereviousPokemonIndex) {
      fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonIndex}/`).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setRandomPokemon(prevState => data))
      setPrevPokemonIndex(pokemonIndex)
      }
    }, [pokemonIndex])
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the suggestion but it only added another API call :D

Comment: Yes cause in the useEffect condition you've `pokemonIndex` when it is changed then only it will call this API